# Replace an image through Django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to replace my homepage image from the Django admin panel. I can upload to my `../media/homepage` directory just fine but I want to first delete any image named "bg.jpg" and rename my new image to "bg.jpg".

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from datetime import datetime

class Homepage(models.Model):
    homepage_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="../media/homepage",blank=True)
    image_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    header_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    header_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Homepage"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Homepage"
```

Also is there any way I can display an image preview in the panel of the current image?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: check topic croping image in django admin in https://inexture-python.gitlab.io/common-notes-all/django/django%20admin/Django_Admin/

Comment: I haven't found anything on how to do it. My guess would be adding a function to my class with `return os.remove("../media/homepage/bg.jpg")` But I need it to delete the current image then rename the new one to "bg.jpg"